# How to use a first solution strategy as an initial solution for a local search metaheuristic?

Tags: python, or-tools

1- i'm trying to work on my Bachelor thesis with OR-Tools and i've landed on the question "How to use the first solution strategy as an initial solution for a local search metaheuristic?"
I'm trying to solve some instances of VRPTW from VRP-REP http://www.vrp-rep.org/variants/item/vrptw.html

I've tried it the same way as in the following Code:

`search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters() search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.LOCAL_CHEAPEST_INSERTION) search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH) search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 60`

the value of the first solution strategy is getting worse and worse as long as i let the solver run!!!
I've tried all combinations between the first_solution_strategy and the local_search_metaheuristic and every time i got a good solution from the first solution strategy it gets worse when i try to improve it using a local search strategy (by worse i mean the solution is increasing while it should be decreasing, because of the method `routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer()` ).

2- is there any other resources where i can find more instances with the optimal solution so i can compare my solution to the optimal one.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: First of all, your question is too broad, you're basically asking for ideas for your thesis (which could results in either no answer or primarily opinion-based answers, which will make the question off-topic). Second, asking for off-site resources, tools, libraries, or tutorials recommendation is off-topic in here. I think you would be better off with having a consultation with your supervisor or do your research and read existing papers.

Comment: And you already asked this on the github issue page. At least, you should indicate that you are cross-posting.

Comment: ty for your response @Andreas but actually i was making sure if my implementation was right and was wandering if there is any other way to do this, which it didn't came to my mind that's all.

And i didn't know that i should indicate the crossposting, ty for telling me that LaurentPerron